# Delete image files (start with same name) based on datetime powershell

Tags: powershell

I need some help in PowerShell script. I've image files and they got datetime in it. I've to read the datetime of same name files and delete the one with old datetime. Any help please?

Here's example and Image format (it follows datetime formate `yyMMddHHmm`)

```
16ABC_1601161253.jpg 
16ABC_1603201502.jpg
15XYZ_1508211653.jpg
15XYZ_1508281253.jpg
```

so in above image number 1 and 3 should be deleted from the folder.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers The answer you provided only solves one part of his question. I have a working script which also deletes the file based on its date. If you reopen this question I can post it.

Comment: The answer would differ only in minor implementation details (sorting/filtering criteria and operation applied to the resulting file list). The general approach is exactly the same in both cases, and the purpose of SO is not to provide solutions tailored to the OP's particular scenario (otherwise there would rarely be the need to close a question as a duplicate).

Comment: I don't need LastWriteTime of the file. I want to extract datetime from the Image name and then work out which is the latest one and delete the old one.

Comment: Anything preventing you from sorting the grouped files by name or basename instead of last modification time?